# how to customize laravel message in a validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

i want to customize my validation messages using the rules that i set before

```
  public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'cuit' => 'required | numeric | digits:11',
                'razon_social' => 'required | alpha | max:64 | min:3',
                'fantasia' => 'required | string | max:255 | min:3',
            ];
        }
```

my messages:

```
 public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'cuit.required' => 'Campo obligatorio',
            'cuit.numeric' => 'El CUITsolo puede ser númerico',
            'cuit.digits' => 'El CUIT debe tener 11 dígitos',

            'razon_social.required' => 'Campo obligatorio',
            'razon_social.alpha' => 'La razón social solo puede ser texto',
            'razon_social.max' => 'La razón social  puede tener hasta 64 caracteres',
            'razon_social.min' => 'La razón social  debe tener al menos 3 caracteres',

            'fantasia.required' => 'Campo obligatorio',
            'fantasia.string' => 'El nombre de fantasía solo puede ser texto',
            'fantasia.max' => 'Este campo puede tener un maximo de 255 caracteres',
            'fantasia.min' => 'Este campo debe tener al menos 3 caracteres',
        ];
    }
}
```

is there a way to call the rules insted of typing de max min characteers? cus if at somepoint i want to change the rules i will have to change the messages as well.

hope u understand what im trying to do.

Comment: Have a read through documentation on [Working with Error Messages](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#specifying-custom-messages-in-language-files).

Comment: Ty for the quick response!! ill  read the doc asap.